# Importing a slow-mo video to Windows

Tags: windows, video, iphone

I recorded a slow-mo video using my iPhone 5s. How do I import that video to my Windows PC without losing the slow-mo effect?

When uploading the video directly to Facebook from the iPhone (from the film roll), the slow-mo effect is preserved (thus, slow-mo effect *is* part of the video file itself).

I've tried with "Import pictures and videos" which gets the video on the PC, but the imported video seems to lose the slow-mo effect both when playing it on the PC and after uploading the imported video to Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

The slow-motion effect applied to the video in Photos.app is not actually applied to the video file. This means that the 120 fps video remains at 120 fps and is played at this higher fps in Windows.

To slow down the video, use a video editor, either on Windows or on the iOS device (such as iMovie which is free on the 5s) to save the slowed video file.

Comment: If that is the case, then why is it apparently possible to upload the video to Facebook and preserve the slow-mo effect? http://www.imore.com/how-record-and-share-slo-mo-video-iphone-5s-including-instagram

Comment: The phone reencodes the video to upload to Facebook, and applies the slow motion effect.

Answer (score 1):

I asked myself the same question. It appears that the best and easiest solution is to buy the Slo-mo app for £0.69 which allows you to choose the slow effect location but then save it as a normal movie file. It can then be played as usual. Bit of the con this as we should be able to do this within the ios iself!

Answer (score 1):

I emailed it to my hotmail account (wouldn't go to my verizon account too big I guess and it's only 4 meg geeze) well went to my hotmail account and worked perfect slo mo and all. then I copied (dragged and dropped to my desktop Windows 7) plyed it from there still slo mo was just the way it was on my IPhone 6 plus.

Answer (score 0):

sending the clip to another apple device using airdrop worked for me

Comment: copy the file to windows after sending it to another apple device using airdrop

Comment: Could you include your comment in your answer with some more detail regarding how you are intending the user copy the file?

Comment: here's what i did. i sent a video from my phone to another iphone 5s through airdrop. when i connected the phone to windows there was another folder, separate from the media folder that contained the video which was perfectly slow.

Comment: here's what i do now. i send videos from my iphone to another iphone via air drop and send it back to my phone. i connect my phone to pc and i works amazingly.....

Answer (score 0):

VLC player is able to play video at 0.1x speed, which roughly corresponds to normal video frame rate.

The slo mo effect is not embedded in the video, because you can edit the start and the beginning of the effect in the device movie editor. My guess is it's <strike>kept in the AAE files</strike> stored somewhere obscure.

**QuickTime**, however has the option "**Play All Frames**" under the "View" menu, which tells it not to drop frames, essentially, not trying to cram 240 frames into a second, but spread them out, which is very similar to the original.