# Slow-mo video is not slow motion after uploading to Google Drive

Tags: iphone, ios, video, whatsapp.app, google-apps

I took a slow-mo video from my iPhone 6 Plus. When I uploaded it to Google Drive the video was without slow-mo. Why is this so? Is this a bug?

I have faced this issue also when uploading the slow-mo video on Hike and WhatsApp.

Comment: Use the iMovie app on iPhone to export the slomo version: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/127445/53510

Answer (score 2):

Slow-mo videos are videos recorded in a higher framerate. To make them slower, Photos plays them back at a lower framerate. This is nothing to do with the file and everything to do with the playback of the file. When you upload the file elsewhere, it's still in a higher framerate, but you're playing it back at this higher framerate. If you want to watch it slower, use Photos to adjust the playback speed.

Comment: use Photos to  adjust speed i didnt got u

Comment: There is an app for OS X that is called "Photos". You can adjust the video there and then export it for use.

Answer (score 0):

Open in QuickTime

Check menu item View -> Play All Frames

QuickTime is really underrated.

What this does is basically tell the player not to drop frames, which it definitely will playing at 240fps, to satisfy a standard playback frame rate. It is off by default.

Comment: take caution that Google might re-encode the video, so avoid that....

Answer (score 0):

- Save the slowmo video from google photos to your device(iPhone)
- Go to 'Photos' App and opent the specific video file
- Click on edit
- Click on Revert>>Revert to Original

Done!